# Shall I have to handle all errno after Linux API or system call failed?

Tags: c, linux

For example, if it failed to invoke msgsnd/msgrcv:

1. How to handle the errno – what is the best way?
2. What principle is applying to business product?
3. Shall I have to cover all of them?
4. What kinds of error must be handled? Do I have to write a signal handler for EINTR or something like this?

Here's my straw-man code:

```
RetVal = msgrcv(... );

   if( RetVal == -1 )
   {
      switch (errno)
      {
      case E2BIG:
           ...
      case EAGAIN:
           ...
      case EFAULT:
           ...
      case EIDRM:
           ...
      case EINTR:
           ...
      case EINVAL:
           ...
      case ENOMEM:
           ...
      default:
           ...
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the coding standards you want to apply, and how you might reasonably respond to the failures.

You *should* always check errors, but you might commonly only handle one or two of them such as EINTR. I would at least try to print some kind of diagnostic last-gasp message before violently exiting in the case of unexpected errors.

The more critical the software, the more carefuly-designed it needs to be, and more comprehensive error handling is part of that.

Since your tags are "C" and "Linux" I assume you're using GCC, in which case have a look at the handy %m in printf.

Comment: `%m` is the same as `%s` with `strerror(errno)` and the latter is a lot more portable.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this too simple for some cases, but until your program is finished something like this is a good stub to have.

```
if(RetVal == -1) {
  perror("message receive");
  exit(1);
}
```

Typically, one only looks at the exact error if a specific recovery is called for in that case. Until you have some code that you need to make conditional on exactly the type of error, you should simply decide between...

1. Silently ignore the error
2. Warn, and then continue
3. Complain, and then exit

See also...

- [the nonstandard-but-useful err(3).](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/err.3.html)
- [setjmp, longjmp, sigsetjmp, et al](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setjmp.3.html)

Comment: The first rule of longjmp() is.. Never talk about longjmp()! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code and what you can do (similar to exception) and what error you have received. For example `EAGAIN` is not a strictly an error (it denotes that you tried non-blocking operation and it would block).

If it is a quick program you may do nothing (say - you just playing with API). If it has GUI it might display a message (say "disk is full" or "cannot connect to network") etc.

If the question had an ultimate answer there would be no need for `errno` - system call could do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The basic Linux system calls almost universally return -1 on error, and 0 or positive value on success. Also, the errno is set to one of the predefined values. So, checking failure of system calls is pretty easy and should be done consistently. Checking the errno for what type of error occurs should be done for the errors you can handle in your program itself. For other errors, it is best to inform the user that he made an error and notify him with the error. The strerror() in the string.h takes erroro as the parameter and returns a pointer to string describing the error.

```
 #include<string.h>

 char* strerror(int errno);
```

After telling the error, it is on the severity of the error whether to continut running the program or exit the program by

```
  exit(1);
```